# Android-Studio: How to change the bounding boxes around parenthesis to underscore, bold, or solid box?

Tags: android-studio, jetbrains-ide

The Android-Studio has this default setting of a bounding box around parenthesis.

[image]

I use VI keymaps and move around rapidly.  These boxes are exploding my brain.  All I can think of are the sprites from Myth.

[image]

How do I change this visual cue?

Comment: Not an Android Studio user, but please check what styles you have got there for `Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Code | Matched brace` (use search box to narrow down possible locations, especially since the path may be different for you). Here is screenshot from PhpStorm (which is also build on IDEA platform). https://postimg.cc/tZVPk8Dt

Comment: This may also be a functionality provided by some custom plugin (e.g. Material Theme UI or perhaps some brackets related one). If so -- try with ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins disable (restart IDE to see the changes).

Comment: @LazyOne second was the trick